# Laravel Mail - Use special character in Sender's Name

Tags: laravel, email, character

I use Laravel 5.8.
And what I'm trying to do is to send an email with sender's name which contain special character such as `TheTh@nos`. And it is not working. The email was sent, but the sender's name will not displayed.

This is my code:

```
Mail::send('emails.purchase-token', $data, function($message){
    $message->from('noreply@thetanos.com', 'TheTh@nos');
    $message->subject('New Tokens Have Been Added To Your Wallet');
    $message->to("recipient01@gmail.com);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is because of how gmail (and most modern e-mail clients) work.

When you put a `@` symbol in the From header field, the email client thinks that you're attempting to spoof the mail to make it look like it originated from a different e-mail address, even though `TheTh@nos` isn't a valid e-mail address.

Try using other special characters in your from and see if that works.

Also, some hosting providers doesn't allow you to change the From header when using their SMTP server.

Comment: if i use gmail as SMTP, it works....but if i use mandrillapp as smtp, it'll not working.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but you can try mb_convert_encoding('TheTh@nos', 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');

Comment: wow...`mb_convert_encoding` is working...you should post as `answer` and i will mark it as correct answer..